# If I have a boolean in a Typescript file, how can I access it in the corresponding HTML file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, boolean

I have a boolean that gets set in a Typescript file of an Angular component, and I want to display some text in the HTML file only when the boolean is true. How can I do this?

Typescript:

```
this.displayButton = true;
```

HTML:

```
<script>
    if ({{ displayButton }} = true) {
        document.write("<span>Some text</span>");
    } else {
        document.write("<span>Some other text</span>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the html format you are using with your Angular project. You are most definitely not following the documentation. Look at @Nicholas K 's answer

Comment: Please read the getting started guide: https://angular.io/start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do so using the `*ngIf` structural directive:

```
<div *ngIf="displayButton">
<span>Some text</span>

<div *ngIf="!displayButton">
<span>Some other text</span>
```

---

Or simply in just one line (as @Plixxer pointed out):

```
<span>{{ displayButton ? 'some text' : 'some other text'}}</span>
```

Comment: Larger applications can get pretty messy with this type of logic. Consider a second solution of <span>{{ displayButton? 'some text' : 'some other text'}}</span>

Comment: Is there a way to make this update when the value of the boolean changes? I would like the text to appear/disappear automatically when the boolean value changes.

Comment: Yes. If you try it, it will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you're having is that you're checking the value of the boolean wrong. You should use two '=' instead of one.

Example:

if ({{ displayButton }} **==** true)

Answer (score 0):

You can use if condition in a tag like this

```
<button *ngIf="this.displayButton =='true'"  >      
            </button>
```

or you can use a function which returns true if variable is set to true

```
<div *ngIf="isResult()">
</div>
```

isResult() is the function which will return Boolean value from .ts file